# retrieve id value from sql database in php which IS NOT last inserted

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database that is designed for Football players and so have the table with the following fields:

- Person_ID
- First_Name
- Surname
- NicName
- Address_Line_1
- Contact_Number
- Date_of_birth
- Postcode

I need to extract the `Person_ID` for a player without actually entering the ID number as players will not know their individual number and is designed to be used just by the system.

I have the My sql code for selecting a player when certain values are entered:

```
SELECT `Person_ID` FROM `person` WHERE `First_Name` = 'A Name' and `Surname` = 'Another Name'
```

This does not however return very well within php when placed into a function. The function I currently have is shown below (php)

```
function showid($fname, $sname, $d) {
    $sql = "SELECT `Person_ID` FROM `person` WHERE `First_Name` = '$fname' and `Surname` = '$sname'";
    $result = mysqli_query($d, $sql);
    if (!$result)
        print ("$sql failed".mysqli_error($d));
    else {
        print ("$fname $sname is selected<br>");
    }
}
```

`$name` and `$sname` are values which will be entered by the user and they will then be able to transfer to a different team or update their account etc but I need to have the ID selected so that further functions and queries can work fully.

Comment: Do you have a column "Person ID" are spaces in columns supported, don't think so?

Comment: They are supported (when enclosed in backticks)- although they're a terrible idea.

Comment: What value is being passed as `$fname` and `$sname`? Do they actually exist in the table? What error is being returned?

Comment: they do exist in the table and have been assigned a unique id. they would be values such as 'John' and 'Smith' for example. there is no error message returned just the names but I cannot figure out how to make it so that the ID is selected and displayed

Comment: 1) Make sure your query is right `var_dump($sql);` 2) Use [**`mysqli::prepare()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) to make sure it's safe 3) Make sure your connection variable is there `var_dump($d);`

Comment: inhan - I have checked that everything is correct. Ideally I would like to instead of Person_ID have a variable such as $person so that it can be used in future functions and code

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding PHP's potential, if that given user you're talking about is logged into your page you could use sessions to store his ID and use it for further iterations with your database without having to query for the user first and last name to find his id and the id will not be shown to the user either. **Also you should use prepared statements since you are already using MySQLi so that you can prevent against MySQL injections.**

Answer (score -1):

If you want to fetch the ID of the selected player, use the fetch_array function

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

```
function showid($fname, $sname, $d) {
    $sql = "SELECT `Person_ID` FROM `person` WHERE `First_Name` = '$fname' and `Surname` = '$sname'";
    $result = mysqli_query($d, $sql);
    if (!$result)
        print ("$sql failed".mysqli_error($d));
    else {
        print ("$fname $sname is selected<br>");
    }

    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    echo "Your ID is" . $row['Person_ID'];
}
```

This of course assumes there is only one result (otherwise we would have to loop) so you might want to check $result->num_rows is equal to 1 and return an error if it isnt (assuming you arent using UNIQUE in your database)